# multiple columns in xsl-fo apache fop

Tags: xml, apache-fop

Is it possible to make multi-column text as in newspaper in using Apache FOP?
It is continuos flow of text and not a table with two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the `column-count` attribute in the `region-body` element.